# $ \left\langle Av,v \right\rangle =0\;\forall v\implies A=0$ confusion

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I want to prove $ \left\langle Av,v \right\rangle =0\;\forall v\implies A=0$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678127/how-do-i-prove-that-left-langle-tx-x-right-rangle-0-forall-x-in-v-righta) is a solution.

But what if we take $A$ to be rotation by $90$ degrees in the plane? It seems $ \left\langle Av,v \right\rangle =0$ is satisfied but $A\neq 0$... Is being a complex vector space crucial here? I'm confused..

Comment: Being a complex vector space is crucial here. For real vector space, you may need $A$ to be self-adjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the fact that $V$ is a complex vector space is crucial.  If $V$ is a real inner-product space, then
$$
\langle A v, v \rangle = 0 \quad \forall v \in V \iff
A^* = -A
$$
You may note that your $90^\circ$ rotation indeed satisfies $A^* = -A$.